# Spring boot liquibase and Flyway build errors

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I am currently facing some strange behaviour. You can find the spring boot app on my github https://github.com/WoistdasNiveau/OegegEtdFullStack/tree/UserDetailsViewFixed currently i am working on the UserDetailsViewFixed branch. For login there are three users predefined in the database on startup : User, Leader and Admin with their corresponding role, respectively. You will need a mysql database for this all the information on the name and how to connect should be in the application.properties file i think, otherwise please write a comment and i will give you further informations.

The Problem: when i run the app via Intellij everything works the app starts and all views and functionality work. However when i user mvn clean and mvn build and then java -jar .... to run the app i get the following errors. I do not understand their origin as i am not sure why i would be forced to use liquibase and flyway when it worked completely fine when started via intellij. I could also not find anything helping me to fix this. Using both packages in the pom.xml still left me with the FlywayMigrationScriptMissingFailureAnalyzer ClassNotFoundException even in intellij. I really do not understand why this happens. I would be very glad if you could have a look at the app so that i can fix these errors and understand their origin.

```
 Unable to instantiate factory class [org.springframework.boot.liquibase.LiquibaseChangelogMissingFailureAnalyzer] for factory type [org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzer]

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: liquibase/exception/ChangeLogParseException
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3373)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructors(Class.java:2060)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader$FactoryInstantiator.findConstructor(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:405)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader$FactoryInstantiator.forClass(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:394)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.instantiateFactory(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:227)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.load(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:206)
        at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers.loadFailureAnalyzers(FailureAnalyzers.java:69)
        at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers.<init>(FailureAnalyzers.java:64)
        at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers.<init>(FailureAnalyzers.java:58)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader$FactoryInstantiator.instantiate(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:382)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.instantiateFactory(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:228)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.load(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:206)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.load(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:160)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:461)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExceptionReporters(SpringApplication.java:802)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:786)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:323)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293)
        at at.oegeg.etd.Application.main(Application.java:20)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:149)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        ... 34 common frames omitted

2023-06-19T13:14:12.974+02:00 TRACE 5816 --- [           main] o.s.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers    : Unable to instantiate factory class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationScriptMissingFailureAnalyzer] for factory type [org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzer]

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationScriptMissingFailureAnalyzer
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:149)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:283)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.instantiateFactory(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:224)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.load(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:206)
        at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers.loadFailureAnalyzers(FailureAnalyzers.java:69)
        at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers.<init>(FailureAnalyzers.java:64)
        at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers.<init>(FailureAnalyzers.java:58)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader$FactoryInstantiator.instantiate(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:382)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.instantiateFactory(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:228)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.load(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:206)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.load(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:160)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:461)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExceptionReporters(SpringApplication.java:802)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:786)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:323)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293)
        at at.oegeg.etd.Application.main(Application.java:20)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)

2023-06-19T13:14:12.980+02:00 TRACE 5816 --- [           main] o.s.c.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader   : Loaded [org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalysisReporter] names: [org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter]
2023-06-19T13:14:12.981+02:00 ERROR 5816 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:164)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:578)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293)
        at at.oegeg.etd.Application.main(Application.java:20)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:488)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:210)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:183)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161)
        ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[] failed to start
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.rethrowDeferredStartupExceptions(TomcatWebServer.java:187)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:126)
        ... 21 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

I would love to understand why it is like this but using mvn install -Pproduction made everything work instead of mvn package.

Comment: You probably have different maven profiles. Please add this information to the question and not as answer, so people can help you find an actual answer to your problem.